Proving that a set is Lebesgue measurable
I'm self studying Capinksi and Kopp's Measure, Integral, and Probability, and I need help completing the following exercise (Exercise 2.8):

Show that that the following two statements is equivalent to saying that $E \in \mathcal{M}$
a) given an $\epsilon > 0$ there is an open set $O \supset E$ with $m^{*}(O \, \backslash \, E) < \epsilon$,
b) given $\epsilon > 0$ there is a closed set $F \subset E$ with $m^{*}(E \, \backslash \, F) < \epsilon$.

Here we're only concerned with subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathcal{M}$ is the collection of all Lebesgue measurable sets, and $m^{*} (A)$ is the outer measure of the set $A$.
The set difference is given by $A \, \backslash B = A \cap B^{c}$, where $B^{c}$ is the complement of $B$.
The exercise has the following solution:

If $E$ is Lebesgue measurable, then existence of $O$ and $F$ is given by Theorems 2.17 and 2.29, respectivelly.
Conversely, let $\epsilon > \frac{1}{n}$, find $O_{n}$, $F_{n}$, and
then $m^{*} \left( \cap O_{n} \, \backslash \, E \right) = 0$,
$m^{*}\left( E \, \backslash \, \cup F_{n} \right) = 0$, so E is Borel
up to null set.
Hence, $E$ is in $\mathcal{M}$.

I don't understand the converse statement at all.
Is there a more "direct" approach to prove the converse statement about the measurability of $E$?
For example, focusing on part a:
We assume $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ and there exists an open set $O \supset E$ with $m^{*}(O \, \backslash \, E) < \epsilon$.
The set $O$ is open and $O \, \backslash \, E$ is null, so both sets are measurable.
Can we use this fact to show that for every set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ we have $$m^{*}(A) = m^{*} (A \cap E) + m^{*} (A \cap E^{c})?$$
Can we do the same for part b?

It may be helpful to see a more detailed version of the proof given by Capinski and Kopp. I think what they have in mind is the following:
Lemma 1: If $A_0\subseteq A_1\subseteq \mathbb R$ where $N=A_1\backslash A_0$ with $N$ is a null set, then
$$
\tag{$\dagger$}
m^*(E\cap A_0) = m^*(E\cap A_1), \quad \forall E \subseteq \mathbb R.
$$
In particular, $A_0$ is measurable if and only if $A_1$ is.
Proof: First note that if $E \subseteq \mathbb R$, then
$$
\begin{split}
m^*(E\cap A_0) &\leq m^*(E\cap A_1) = m^*(E\cap A_0 \sqcup E\cap N) \\
&\leq m^*(E\cap A_0)+ m^*(E\cap N) \\
&= m^*(E\cap A_0),
\end{split}
$$
since $E\cap N\subseteq N$ and so must be a null set. It follows that $m^*(E\cap A_0) = m^*(E\cap A_1)$ for all $E\subseteq \mathbb R$. Next note that $A_0^c=A_1^c\cup N$, hence applying $(\dagger)$ to the pair $A_1^c \subseteq A_0^c$ we find that $m^*(E\cap A_0^c) = m^*(E\cap A_1^c)$ for all $E \subseteq \mathbb R$. It follows immediately that
$$
m^*(E\cap A_0)+ m^*(E\cap A_0^c) = m^*(E\cap A_1) + m^*(E\cap A_1^c),
$$
and hence $A_0$ is measurable if and only if $A_1$ is measurable.
Lemma 2:

If $A\subseteq \mathbb R$ is such that, for any $\epsilon>0$, there is an open set $U$ containing $A$ such that $m^*(U \backslash A) < \epsilon$, then $A$ is measurable.
Similarly if $B\subseteq \mathbb R$ is such that for any $\epsilon>0$ there is a closed set $F$ such that $F \subseteq B$ and $m^*(B\backslash F)< \epsilon$ then $B$ is measurable.

Proof: For each $n\in \mathbb N$, let $U_n$ be an open subset of $\mathbb R$ such that $A\subseteq U_n$ and $m^*(U_n\backslash A) < \frac{1}{n}$. Let $U_0 = \bigcap_{n \geq 1} U_n$. Then $A \subseteq U_0$ and since $m^*(U_0\backslash A)<\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n\geq 0$ it follows that $m^*(U_0\backslash A)=0$, that is, $A \subseteq U_0$ differ by a set of measure zero. Since open sets are measurable $\mathcal U_0$ is measurable, and hence by Lemma $1$, $A$ is measurable.
For part $2$, note that $A$ is measurable if and only if $A^c$ is measurable, and if, for every $\epsilon>0$ there is an open set $U$ containing $A^c$ with $m^*(U\backslash A^c)<\epsilon$, then if we let $F = U^c$, $F$ is closed and is a subset of $A$, with $m^*(A\backslash F) = m^*(U\cap A)< \epsilon$. Thus condition $1$ for $A^c$ is equivalent to condition $2$. for $A$, and we are done.
Finally, note that Capinski and Kopp define a measure $\mu$ to be regular if parts 1. and 2. of Lemma 2 hold for $\mu$. This seems to me to be somewhat non-standard: if $\mu$ satisfies $1$. it is usually referred to as outer regular while $\mu$ is said to be inner regular if $\mu(A) = \text{sup}\{\mu(F): F\subseteq A,F \text{ compact}\}$.

I think the following answers might work, so I posted them as an answer:

Let's assume $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, and for a given $\epsilon >
    0$ there exists an open set $O \supset E$ such that $m^{*} (O \cap
    E^{c}) < \epsilon$. For an arbitary $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, we
want to show that $$m^{*}(A) = m^{*} (A \cap E) + m^{*} (A \cap
E^{c}).$$ As $O$ is open, it is measurable, and we have $$ m^{*}(A)
= m^{*} (A \cap O) + m^{*} (A \cap O^{c}). $$ The set $O \cap E^{c}$ is null, and therefore measurable, and we can apply its
measurability to the set $A \cap O$, obtaining: \begin{align*} m^{*}
(A \cap O) &= m^{*} (A \cap O \cap O \cap E^{c}) + m^{*}\left(A \cap
O \cap \left(O \cap E^{c}\right)^{c} \right) \\ &= m^{*} (A \cap
E^{c}) + m^{*}\left(A \cap O \cap \left( O^{c} \cup E \right)
\right). \end{align*} If I drew my Venn diagrams correctly, it
follows that $$ A \cap O \cap \left( O^{c} \cup E \right) = A \cap O
\cap E = A \cap E,$$ and $$ m^{*} (A \cap O) = m^{*} (A \cap E^{c})
+ m^{*} (A \cap E).$$ Similarly, we can apply $O \cap E^{c}$'s measurability to $A \cap O^{c}$, obtaining: \begin{align*} m^{*} (A
\cap O^{c}) &= m^{*} (A \cap O^{c} \cap O \cap E^{c}) + m^{*}\left(A
\cap O^{c} \cap \left(O \cap E^{c}\right)^{c} \right) \\ &= m^{*}
(\varnothing) +  m^{*}\left(A \cap O^{c} \cap \left(O^{c} \cup
E\right) \right) \\ &= m^{*} (\varnothing) + m^{*} (\varnothing) \\
&= 0 \end{align*} Thus, $m^{*}(A) = m^{*} (A \cap E) + m^{*} (A \cap
E^{c})$ as desired. Hopefully, this isn't wrong.
Let's assume $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, and for a given $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a closed set $F \subset E$ such that $m^{*} (E \cap F^{c}) < \epsilon$.
We want to prove that for an arbitary $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ the following holds: $$m^{*} (A) = m^{*} (A \cap F) + m^{*} (A \cap F^{c}).$$
As $F$ is closed, $F^{c}$ is open and measurable, $F^{c} \in \mathcal{M}$, and it follows that $F \in \mathcal{M}$.
Now, we can write: $$m^{*} (A) = m^{*}(A \cap F) + m^{*}(A \cap F^{c}).$$
We can also apply $F$'s measurability to the set $A \cap E$, then it follows that
\begin{align*}
m^{*}(A \cap E) &= m^{*} (A \cap E \cap F) + m^{*} (A \cap E \cap F^{c}) \\
&= m^{*} (A \cap F) + 0,
\end{align*}
as $F \subset E$ and $A \cap E \cap F^{c}$ is null by our assumption.
As $A \cap E \cap F^{c}$ is null, it measurable, and we can apply its measurability to $A \cap F^{C}$:
\begin{align*}
m^{*} (A \cap F^{c}) &= m^{*}\left(A \cap F^{c} \cap E \cap F^{c}) + m^{*} (A \cap F^{c} \cap \left( E \cap F^{c} \right)^{c} \right) \\
&= 0 + m^{*} \left(A \cap F^{c} \cap \left( E \cap F^{c} \right)^{c} \right).
\end{align*}
Since $A \cap F^{c} \cap \left( E \cap F^{c} \right)^{c} = A \cap E^{c},$ it follows that
$$ m^{*} (A \cap F^{c}) = m^{*} ( A \cap E^{c}). $$
Combining our results, we obtain $$m^{*}(A) = m^{*}(A \cap E) + m^{*}(A \cap E^{c})$$ and $E$ is measurable.


You can't conclude $O \cap E^c$ is null. $O$ was determined for a given positive $\epsilon$, and a smaller $\epsilon$ might require a different $O$.
